# How to vectorize Numpy Array Modification like in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Using Matlab you can modify an array from indices using vectorization :

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Output :

```
A =

 1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
```

Modifying :

```
A([2,4,6:9]) = -1
```

Output :

```
A =

 1    -1     3    -1     5    -1    -1    -1    -1
```

How can we do that using Numpy Python ?

Comment: `A[np.r_[1,3,5:8]]=-1`?

Comment: Thks Quang Hoang ! It works fine :-) !

Comment: In effect `np.r_` is doing the same thing as MATLAB `[2,4,6:9]`, expanding and concatenating to create an array of individual indices.  MATLAB wraps a lot of functionality in that `[...]` syntax.  In python that syntax is restricted to lists and indexing (which is what `r_` is 'pretending' to do!).

Answer (score 2):

You can't combine a fancy integer index and a slice like that in numpy, so you have two options:

1. Convert the slice to numerical indices:

   ```
   A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
   A[[1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]] = -1
   ```

   Notice the double square brackets: the index is a list of integers.
2. Set the fancy index and slice separately:

   ```
   A[[1, 3]] = A[5:9] = -1
   ```

   Notice that the right bound of a slice is exclusive in python and indices are zero based.